# 'sqlite3.h' file not found after pod 'FirebaseMessaging' update

Tags: sqlite, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been using `pod 'FirebaseMessaging'` successfully for a while:

```
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '2.2.0'
```

Tried updating to a new version

```
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '3.0.0'
```

but the project doesn't build. It shows an error that **'sqlite3.h' file not found**.

Changed the source the way it is [described](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseMessaging) in their documentation:

```
pod 'FirebaseCore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
```

The error still exists.

So, is there a way to fix this?

**P.S.**

I have another pod which also uses sqlite:

```
pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher', '3.0.2'
```

> Xcode 9.3 (9E145)
>
> CocoaPods 1.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [FirebaseMessaging bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1283). The workaround and fix is to change the failing compile line to have brackets instead of quotes:

`#import <sqlite3.h>`

FirebaseMessaging 3.0.0 was released as source for the first time. Previously it had been a binary CocoaPod. When another CocoaPod adds another version of a header named `sqlite3.h`, the Xcode header map feature causes the system `sqlite3.h` to no longer be findable unless it is properly imported with brackets. System headers should be imported with brackets. The issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/1285) for the next Firebase patch release. In the meantime, please use the workaround.